# Bootstrap - additional margin

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I use bootstrap. I have two divs. This is my code html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-12 circle lg-circle">
    <div class="col-12 circle sm-circle">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And css

```
.circle {
  border: solid 0.9px $athens-gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.lg-circle {
  max-height: 69.375rem;
  max-width: 69.375rem;
  padding: 7.125rem;
}

.sm-circle {
  border-color: $athens-dark;
  max-height: 69.375rem;
  max-width: 55.0625rem;
}
```

and this is the view from the browser.

**Question:** Why is there a right margin, how to remove it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

add this code to css file:

```
.container{
    margin:unset;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this into your

```
.container{
    margin:auto;
}
.col-12{
    margin:auto;
}
```